# The S-340 cipher

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, word-search

[image]

Transcription:

```
TIEICHJBEE
EIHRONHOOY
YTRNISNGAP
NEDHRTSTTS
HTGYAEOEIP
NSUEAEOPWR
SDMZPCSUUA
ZYAEYZZKOE
INZTRDFLLX
SNYSMARTIE
```

Hint:

> Heavily inspired by another cipher hinted in the title.

Partial solutions and ideas are welcome in either the comment section or the answer section.

Comment: I think the L at R9C9 should be a J :-)

Comment: @SnySmartie They're making a joke, because then that section of the cipher would read `FLJX`, i.e. their username.

Comment: My bad... I'll add these jokes in for my next puzzle lol :)

Comment: And R3C9 should be `Y`, and R6C3 and R7C3 should be `K` and `R` respectively?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following the L shape pattern on the Z-340 cipher:

> [image]

I got

> This in my fiirst pszzlee on thu pzlsing steck xnchange as oiy hope yeu ensjoy da ouzzm by the pay ta eerrows arre interdedt

This results in with 6th row shifted one step to the left and the final row’s letter being negated:

> THIS IS MY FIRST PUZZLE ON THE PZLING STACK XCHANGE SO I HOPE YOU ENJOY DA PUZZ. BY THE WAY TE ERRORS ARE INTENDED

Or more elegantly put

> This is my first puzzle on the puzzling stack exchange so I hope you enjoy the puzzle. By the way the errors are intended

Answer (score 8):

This is

> A variation of the Zodiac Z-340 cipher. This is a "S-340" cipher because the author's username is **S**ny **S**martie.

To solve the cipher, you need to

> Use the same trick as the Z-340 cipher, going through the grid with L-shape movement. There is a twist, though: every 4 movements (roughly), you need to go one more to the right then go back to the original pattern, and every 8 movements (roughly) you need to skip a letter. I’m not sure when you’re supposed to exactly make these twists, I basically did them every time I needed something readable while solving the puzzle. See the following grid:

> [image]

Therefore, the message is

> **THIS IS MY FIRST PUZZLE ON THE PZLNG STACK XCHANGE SO I HOPE YOU ENJOY DA PUZZ BY THE WAY TE ERRORS ARE INTENDED**

Comment: Not exactly; you always follow the L-shape movement, but rot13(yvar gra vf fxvccrq fvapr vg vf whfg zl hfreanzr naq yvar fvk unf orra fuvsgrq gb gur evtug vagragvbanyyl fb lbh unir gb erirefr gung).

Comment: Oh, right, that works better! I think PDT edited his answer with this explanation; I’ll left mine untouched ;)